# Problem 1: Sophism MIR publication

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time

I am trying to solve the very first problem  from the book *["Physical Paradoxes and Sophism"](https://archive.org/details/LangePhysicalParadoxesAndSophismsScienceForEveryoneMir1987/page/n13/mode/2up)*
The problem is as under:

> 1.1. The Amazing Adventure of a Subway Passenger:
>
> Every morning a muscovite goes to work by a subway train. Although he starts work at the same time every day, he arrives at the subway station at various times each day. For simplicity, we can assume that the time he arrives at the station is quite random.
> On the face of it, he thought likely to assume that the first train, after he reaches the platform, goes the opposite way.
> But how was he amazed to find that half as many trains go his way.
> He decided to clarify the reason for this mysterious phenomenon and began to go to work from another station further away. His new observations made even more amazed since at the later station the case was perfectly different: the number of trains going his way was three times as many as those going the opposite way. Could you help the passenger to resolve the strange behavior of the subway trains?

---

The solution is also [given in the book](https://archive.org/details/LangePhysicalParadoxesAndSophismsScienceForEveryoneMir1987/page/n113/mode/2up). But I am not able to understand it.
Specifically, the last paragraph where the author is talking about going form farther station is also not clear to me.

[image]

In the given solution, the author explains through this fig. Here also how can he take the  trains position like this. And how to achieve three times frequency, that s also not mentioned the solution.

It looks like an interesting problem to think over. Any idea what exactly is going on?